# python requests library redirect new page to post request

Tags: python, redirect, post, request

I am a newbie in python, and I have to retrieve the data of this page.
http://mims.com/india/drug/search?q=dextro but as this website requires user
login so I went through the following code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
POST_LOGIN_URL = "https://sso.mims.com/Account/Signin"
REQUEST_URL    = "https://mims.com/india/drug/search?q=DEXTRO%20PLUS"
payload = {
    "EmailAddress": "email address here",
    "Password"    : "password here"
}
with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post(POST_LOGIN_URL, data=payload)
    r = session.get(REQUEST_URL)
    with open('abc.html', 'wb')as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

Instead of showing the desired result, it is redirecting me to a page and I am getting a "FORM" element which contains method="post" request and a button which autoclicks.
So I am unable to figure it out please someone help.

Comment: It's hard to figure out without access to the site (or to the source code of the response, and potentially the response headers, too)

Comment: you can login with your mail id and can use those credentials while applying post request..

Comment: I would have shared my credentials, but it's free to sign up.. so please help me out if u can..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using **selenium webdriver** and **wait** after login or any other **GET** request.
 So that background request completes it's execution and return to the required page.

***Whenever you face redirections while Sending any GET request, add SLEEP(seconds) method it can solve many problems***